# CCAdvancedMenu boundaryRect

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Hoping someone can help me with this... I'm following examples seen [here for CCMenuAdvanced](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14095) but am ending up with a weird result, I see my menu and it scrolls but using the boundaryRect property I can't seem to get it to hide part of the menu and show what I want.

Here's my code:

```
// Setup Menu Alignment
[menuA alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:0 bottomToTop:NO]; //< also sets contentSize and keyBindings on Mac
menuA.isRelativeAnchorPoint = YES;

menuA.boundaryRect = CGRectMake(0, 100, 230, 200);

[menuA fixPosition];
[self addChild:menuA];
```

I'm able to scroll and view my entire list which is good, but I can't set up an area to view only part of the menu at a time, which is what boundaryRect should do. Has anyone used this before and can give me some advice?!?

Thanks!

Comment: Have the same problem - want to use CCMenuAdvanced, but boundaryrect seems to be ignored - The documentation at http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/1.0/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/html/interface_c_c_menu_advanced.html#a4c952110a7c23d8baa358bd42b1605f1 is rather cryptic and states that the boundaryrect should be LARGER than the menu's bounding box - I don't understand how that will cause it to scroll (since the menu will then be entirely within the 'hole' in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not from the same class, but a home grown scrolling menu. I use the visibility and transparencies of the menuItems themselves. When scrolling up, if a menu label approaches the rectangle's edge, i start fading it out to 0. When the anchor point of the menuItem is outside the rectangle, i set its visibility to NO (thus cant be clicked).  Same going down. Clamping is tricky. You have to set these properties when the list of menuItems changes, in case it grows shorter than the height of the boundary rectangle, or grows again greater than the rectangle. Something like this (edited, not actual code ... dont know if it compiles :) ):

```
-(void) fixMenuItemOpacity:(CCMenuItemLabel*) mi{

    float theY = mi.position.y ;

    if (fadeOutZoneHeight_<4.0f) {
        if (theY> self.boundaryRect.origin.y+self.boundaryRect.size.height/2 - fadeOutZoneHeight_) {
            mi.visible=NO;
        } else if( theY < self.boundaryRect.origin.y-self.boundaryRect.size.height/2 + fadeOutZoneHeight_) {
            mi.visible=NO;
        } else {
            mi.visible=YES;
        }
        return;
    }
    float delta;
    float percentOpacity;

    float topWindow;
    float bottomWindow;
    float top;
    float bottom;

    /*

     not visible

     --------------------------- top
     visible, variable opacity
     --------------------------- top window




     opacity 100%




     --------------------------  bottomWindow
     visible, variable opacity
     -------------------------   bottom

     */

    top = self.boundaryRect.origin.y + self.boundaryRect.size.height/2;
    topWindow = top - fadeOutZoneHeight_;
    bottom = self.boundaryRect.origin.y - self.boundaryRect.size.height/2;
    bottomWindow=bottom+ fadeOutZoneHeight_;

    if (theY> top ) {
        mi.visible=NO;
    } else if ( (theY > topWindow) && (theY < top)) {
        mi.visible=YES;
        delta = abs((int)top - (int)theY);
        percentOpacity=delta/fadeOutZoneHeight_;
        mi.opacity=(GLubyte )(255.0f*percentOpacity);
    } else if( (theY <= topWindow ) && (theY >= bottomWindow ) ){
        mi.opacity=255;
        mi.visible=YES;

    } else if ( (theY < bottomWindow) && (theY >= bottom) ){
        mi.visible=YES;
        delta= abs((int)bottom - (int)theY);
        percentOpacity = delta/fadeOutZoneHeight_;
        mi.opacity=(GLubyte ) (255.0*percentOpacity);
    } else {
        mi.visible=NO;
    }


}
```